# pywinauto: нужна книга или курс в тексте

Tags: pywinauto

Есть ли по этой библиотеке книга или полноценный учебный курс в текстовом формате (например, в стиле Прохорёнка / Дронова)? Сам пока не нашёл.

Comment: Думаю, вряд ли. Есть только обзорная видео лекция на Хабре и ещё пара статей там же. Идея сделать курс - отличная. Но пока у самих хватает сил только следующий мажорный релиз пилить (довольно медленно) с поддержкой Линукса и Макоси, а также с улучшениями на винде. До документации полноценно руки дойдут нескоро. Если только кто-то случайно возьмётся и поможет.